# Задача о сортировке моментов времени

Tags: delphi

Я изучаю делфи и столкнулся с 2 задачами, с которыми я не могу справиться.

Во входном файле записано сначала число `N (1<=N<=100)`, а затем
`N` моментов времени. Каждый момент времени задается 3 целыми числами - 
часы (от 0 до 23), минуты (от 0 до 60) и секунды (от 0 до 60).
В выходной файл `ANSWER.txt` выведите моменты времени, упорядоченные в порядке неубывания (момент времени также выводится в виде трех чисел, ведущие нули выводить не обязательно).

Пример входного файла:

```
4
10 20 30
7 30 00
23 59 59
13 30 30
```

Пример выходного файла:

```
7  30  0
10 20 30
13 30 30
23 59 59
```

Помогите решить.

Comment: С чем конкретно не справляетесь ( кодинг, алгоритм, русский язык ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Один из простейших методов решения - представить 3 числа времени как одно число. Т.е. 7.30.00 (из примера) представить как 73000. Таким образом, считываешь количество моментов времени, создаешь массив, заполняешь его моментами времени в сказанном выше представлении. Далее идет простейшая сортировка массива по возрастанию и вывод в выходной файл. При выводе  следует опять разбить наше большое число на три пары меньше.